# Is there a way to sort values of one column (min to max) based on the values of another column that contain repeated text values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtfs

I am working with a dataset which is of the form (just a sample)

```
ID    Name              Diff
14865 Aalsmeerdrweg     9.9754
14865 Aalsmeerdrweg     65.0246
14820 Aalsmeerdrweg 142 17.0244
14820 Aalsmeerdrweg 142 -4.9756
```

Is there some way to sort the values of the column 'Diff' (min to max) for all the same values in the column 'Name'? Furthermore, once it is sorted, some way to remove the values the smallest 'x' number of values? (here x is the number of times a name is repeated)??

Comment: I think you should try using Pandas, which will allow you to order multiple columns as if you were working on Excel. Look for this "Sort by multiple columns" on this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Answer (score 0):

.sort_values() sorts in the sorder you provide the columns.
So it first sorts by Name and after that for each name by Diff

```
df.sort_values(["Name", "Diff"], ascending = True)
```